# Detect blur aka losing focus of a Draft.js editor

Tags: javascript, draftjs

Is there a "correct way" to detect if I lose focus of a Draft.js editor?

The use case is, that I want "quit editor mode" if the user clicks elsewhere which means that I toggle the readOnly prop of the editor. How can I do this ideally and is it a good idea to do that (do you see problems with that)?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can catch the blur event fired around your draft editor just with a good old `onBlur`

```
<Editor onBlur={this.onBlur}
```

Isn't this enough for your scenario?